# Java / Android wait until a thread has finished before running a new method

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an android application (written in java) which has two buttons (**connect** and **request data**).

When each button is clicked, a task is performed and a **progress dialog** appears to display how much the task has completed.

In order to show the progress dialog, when each button is clicked, the task is run on a thread.

The **connect** button just has one task - run on the thread. However, the **request data** button executes two tasks - the first task on the thread similar to the connect button but also a second task, **refreshInfo()** which must be run after the first task on the thread, **progThread** is finished.

```
private Button connectButton;
private Button requestDataButton;

private ProgressDialog connectionDialog;
private ProgressDialog requestDataDialog;

private ProgressThread progThread;

private int currentDialog;

public void connectClick(View view)      //When the connect button is clicked
{
    performAction(1);   //Run the thread to perform the action
}

public void requestDownloadClick(View view)   //When the request data button is clicked
{
    performAction(2);    //Run the thread to perform the action

    refreshInfo();    //Do something else
}

private void performAction(int type)
{
    currentDialog = type;

    showDialog(type);

    try 
    {
        progThread.join();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The key method here is **performAction(int type)**. I basically don't want this method to complete until **progThread** has finished running.

As you can see, I've tried **progThread.join()** to prevent the method from continuing until **progThread** has finished running, however as **progThread** involves displaying a **Progress Dialog**, running **progThread.join()** seems to prevent the **Progress Dialog** from showing, as currently when you click the button, the first task is performing but the dialog only flashes up at the end.

Can anyone think of a way to run the thread, showing the **Progress Dialog** as normal and then running the second method (if there is one).

I've included the thread code below incase it is needed.

```
private class ProgressThread extends Thread 
{   
    final static int DONE = 0;
    final static int RUNNING = 1;   // Class constants defining state of the thread

    private Handler progressHandler;
    int mState;
    int total;

    ProgressThread(Handler _handler)    // Constructor with an argument that specifies Handler on main thread to which messages will be sent by this thread.
    {
        progressHandler = _handler;
    }

    public void run()    // Invoked automatically when the Thread starts.  
    {
        mState = RUNNING;   

        updateProgressBar();

        connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        requestDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRequestDownload);

        while (mState == RUNNING) 
        {
            if (currentDialog == 1)
            {
                try
                { 
                    doSomething();

                    if (something)
                    {
                        setState(DONE);

                        total = 100;

                        updateProgressBar();

                        removeDialog(1);

                        connectButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        total = total + 20;

                        if (something has reached a limit)
                        {
                            setState(DONE);

                            total = 0;

                            updateProgressBar();

                            removeDialog(1); 
                        }
                    }

                    updateProgressBar();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

            if (currentDialog == 2)
            {
                try
                {
                    doSomething();

                    total = 10;

                    updateProgressBar();

                    doSomething();

                    total = 70;

                    updateProgressBar();

                    if (something)  //If the download info has not been got
                    {
                        setState(DONE);

                        total = 0;

                        updateProgressBar();

                        removeDialog(2);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                connectButton.setEnabled(true);

                                requestDataButton.setEnabled(true);
                            }                               
                        });  
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        total = 100;

                        updateProgressBar();

                        setState(DONE);

                        removeDialog(2);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                requestDataButton.setEnabled(false);
                            }                               
                         }); 
                     }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    removeDialog(2);

                    setState(DONE);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            connectButton.setEnabled(true);

                            requestDataButton.setEnabled(true);
                        }                               
                    });  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Set current state of thread (use state=ProgressThread.DONE to stop thread)
    public void setState(int state) 
    {
        mState = state;
    }

    public void updateProgressBar()
    {
        Message msg = progressHandler.obtainMessage();   // Send message (with current value of  total as data) to Handler on UI thread so that it can update the progress bar

        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putInt("total", total);

        msg.setData(b);

        progressHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

final Handler handler = new Handler()     // Handler on the main (UI) thread that will receive messages from the second thread and update the progress.
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");             // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data and update the progress bar

        switch (currentDialog)
        {
        case 1 : 
            connectionDialog.setProgress(total);
            break;

        case 2 : 
            requestDataDialog.setProgress(total);
            break;
        }
    }
};

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{   
    switch (currentDialog)
    {
    case 1 :
        connectionDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        connectionDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        connectionDialog.setMax(100);

        connectionDialog.setProgress(0);

        connectionDialog.setMessage("Connecting To The Device");

        progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);

        progThread.start();

        return connectionDialog;

    case 2 :
        requestDataDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        requestDataDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        requestDataDialog.setMax(100);

        requestDataDialog.setProgress(0);

        requestDataDialog.setMessage("Requesting Download Data");

        progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);

        progThread.start();

        return requestDataDialog;

    default : 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read Java Synchronization, and wait objects, it requires proper understanding of JAVA to run threads order wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android API provides an [`AsyncTask` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which has two methods `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`. You'll have to override both of them, do whatever you have to do in `doInBackground` and when the job is done `onPostExecute` callback will be run.
There's also an `onProgressUpdate` callback which is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Look at AsyncTask class. It should be able to do what you want.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems other answers have you covered. AsyncTask is the way to go.

However if you want to push through with your Thread implementation, just `start()` the next thread at the end of the first thread's run method.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna give the Async Task a go :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a [CountdownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) of size 1